# Mysqldump by date range or first X entries?

Tags: database, backup, mysql

If I have a large database with hundreds of tables, and I only want to mysqldump the data from the first month, how would I do that?

Also acceptable would be the first X entries in the DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a "where" condition on the command line.

See the manual: [--where](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)